# Transfer image from one VC to another not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I would like for an image, when clicked upon, to go to another view controller so that they can view the image by itself! I am having a little trouble doing so and I am not sure exactly how to get it to go there!

This variable is declared as a PFObject

```
var postsArray = [PFObject]()
```

This code is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath tableView function

```
postsArray[indexPath.row]["image"].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                postCellObj.postImage.image = downloadedImage
                postCellObj.postImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                postCellObj.postImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

            }
        }
```

I have a button overlayed on top of the button so when the button is clicked, I need for the image to go to another VC like I said above. This is the code in my prePareForSegue function

```
if username != PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

   let profileVC: UserProfileViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UserProfileViewController
   profileVC.usernameString = username

   } else if segue.identifier == "toPhotoView" {
    let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoViewController
    dvc.newImage = postImage

}
```

And in my other view controller, or the destination view controller, I need for the image that was clicked on to appear but cant figure it out! So this is the small bit of code in the destination view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    var newImage: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    image.image = newImage

}
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do so just because of the fact that this is in a Parse array and it's throwing me off, can anybody help me out?

Comment: Try the `image.image = newImage` in viewWillAppear.  If that doesn't do it, then you'll know you have a problem with setting postImage after the segue is triggered.

Comment: Do I have to use DidSelectRowAtIndexPath in order to get the image that is selected?

Comment: I am just not sure how to get the image that is selected, because I'm not clicking on the image, Im clicking on a transparent button on top of the image.

Comment: Well, you could tag the button with the indexPath.row, and use that to get the image from the array you're populating the table with.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues should be easy to debug if you know how to.

Simply add some break points at `dvc.newImage = postImage` and `image.image = newImage`, launch the app, click on the cell, and watch the variables.

Normally, the code you gave seems fine. You can check if `postImage` is a valid object, and in `viewDidLoad`, you can check if `dvc.newImage` is the image you need.

If the images are correctly initialized and assigned, you are good to go.

BTW, I suspect either the `image`(which is a `UIImageView`, and you should change its name to reflect what's its class) is nil or your `newImage` is not valid

Some useful lldb command like `po`:

`po image.image`
`po newImage`

Comment: `dvc.newImage = postImage` says that is is an unresolved identifier so I am not exactly sure how I am getting the image. Do I need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: which is unresolved identifier? postImage or dvc.newImage? i have no idea how you get postImage. You just use it in your post

Comment: @GriffinMorandini again, I have show you the skill to debug, you should master it. we know nothing about your project